# Monads 'red pipe' different from type?

Tags: haskell, monads

I was [reading an interesting article](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2013/02/11/demand-more-from-your-programming-language/) about monad, 'pipes' and being a 'red pipe'. From what it seems it is saying function parameters or classes are types of pipes to make sure everything fits. Then it goes about being a red pipe and must always be a red pipe and purity. This part I didn't understand

Why can't a 'red pipe' become a 'blue pipe'? Can a red pipe be converted to a plain pipe? What does this have to do with purity? and can I think of this being something like `class RedPipe: PlainPipe { /* same interface and implementation here*/ }` ?

Comment: Don't waste your time with cute allegoric description of mathematical concepts such as monads. Study the actual mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Haskell, the type of a function tells you exactly what it does and, more importantly, what it does NOT do.  This makes it easier to reason about Haskell code.

For example, if I have a function of the following type:

```
f :: Int -> Int
```

I know that it takes an `Int` as input and produces an `Int` as output, and it does nothing else.  Importantly, I know it has no side effects.

If I have a function of type:

```
g :: Double -> State Int Double
```

... that function takes a `Double` as an argument and produces a way to produce a `Double`, but only if I allow it to consult or modify some `Int` state.

If I have a function of type:

```
h :: Int -> Maybe String
```

I know that this function takes an `Int` and might produce a `String`, or it might fail, producing nothing.  Notice that none of the previous two functions returned `Maybe`, meaning that they could NOT fail.  Haskell does not permit failure (i.e. nullable values) by default.

If I have a function of type:

```
i :: String -> IO ()
```

I know that this function takes a `String` and can be run to produce side effects.  Note that none of the previous functions had an `IO` in their type, meaning that they could not produce side effects.  Haskell does not permit side effects by default.  You must explicitly opt in to them in the type.

This means that we can look at the types of functions or values and immediately understand what features they are using.  So, for example, if I see a `Maybe` in the type, I know there is a potential to fail, and if I don't, then I know there is no potential to fail.  Similarly, if I see an `IO` in the type, then I know there is a potential for side effects, but if I see no `IO` in the type, then there is no potential for side effects.

In mainstream languages, you don't have this ability to selectively "opt-in" to features.  All features are on by default, all the time, meaning that you must always check for `null` because you have no way to guarantee that some function didn't fail, and you must always run tests because you have no way to guarantee that some function didn't implicitly modify the state of your system.

Haskell lets you restrict the behaviors of functions to give you finer grained control over their "permissions", which makes it easier to scale to large programs without bugs and also makes it easier to read and understand Haskell code because the type enumerates the full range of the code's behaviors, so you never have to understand more than what the type permits.

Comment: Great answer but I have a few more questions. Does `State` and `IO ()` have a special meaning or are they user/library defined types? If i had to guess `State` means it modifies global variables (which I don't understand because I thought everything was read only/pure) and `IO()` means the data will not be the same even if the same parameters are called repeatedly. But I'm not sure why there are `()` after the IO. Is IO a type and `()` have a meaning?

Comment: `State` is purely a library type and has no language or compiler support.  `State s a` is `s -> (a, s)` under the hood.  In other words, every `State s a` value is actually a pure function that takes an initial state and returns a value plus a final state.  `IO` has some compiler support.  The `()` in the `IO` type does have meaning.  `IO` actions can return values, like `getLine :: IO String`.  The `()` means it returns a useless empty value and that we are really only using it for its side effects (kind of like a `void` function in C/Java).

Comment: @BruteCode Forgot to @ you on my last comment, but I also wanted to mention that if you want to understand `IO` better, I recommend you read [this post of mine](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/01/introduction-to-haskell-io.html) that more carefully explains the distinction between evaluating an `IO` action and running it.

Answer (score 3):

The author is using the terms "red pipe" and "blue pipe" as a metaphor. As far as I know, that's not widely used terminology. I think the key point of his article is that type safety provided by languages such as Java help to catch some kinds of programmer mistakes, isolating *pure* from *impure* functions can catch even more. Using one of his examples:

```
square :: Double -> Double
```

This type signature tells me that

1. The function `square` doesn't have any side effects. It's not going to sneak off and update a database, or print something to the screen, or change some state data, or otherwise surprise me. (In Java, or C, for example, I would have to read the function and any functions it calls, or rely on the documentation, to know what the function does.)
2. Every time I call it with a particular value, say, `square 5`, I will get exactly the same result. This is called *referential transparency*, and it allows the compiler to do some optimisation because it knows that this value will never change, so it only needs to be calculated once.